# How to make GCC warn unmatched number of arguments in function calls and function definition?

Tags: c, function, gcc

I have two files.

The first file contains the function prototype and the main function calls myfunc with only one argument:

```
int myfunc (int x);
int main ()
{
    int x =5;
    myfunc(x);
}
```

and the second file contains the function definition but with 2 arguments:

```
int myfunc (int x, int y)
{
        return x+y;
}
```

When I tried to compile this two files using GCC I got no errors or warnings.

How to force GCC to warn about something like this??

Comment: The above is a linking problem and the gcc can warn only when the program is linked. Till that i dont think you can get any error message.

Answer (score 8):

Put your prototypes in a header file, and `#include` the header file in all source files which use the functions.

GCC compiles each file independently, so it cannot know that the definition of the function does not correspond to the declaration unless the declaration is also included in the file with the definition.

It should look like this:

#### myfunc.h

```
#ifndef MYFUNC_H
#define MYFUNC_H

int myfunc (int x);

#endif
```

#### myfunc.c

```
#include "myfunc.h"

int myfunc (int x, int y)
{
        return x+y;
}
```

#### main.c

```
#include "myfunc.h"

int main ()
{
    int x =5;
    myfunc(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the two source files are two different [*translation units*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) that are compiled completely separately, it's impossible for the compiler to know about this. And as C symbols doesn't really have information about arguments, the linker can't warn about this either.

The only solution is to put function prototypes in header files that are included in all relevant source files.

Comment: The linker *could* be made to warn about this but apparently there is not a high demand

Comment: @MattMcNabb It could *if* the compiler stored information about the number of arguments a function takes in the object files. I don't think many C compilers do that (unlike C++ where it's part of the symbol names).